# Set 3d cube rotation origin

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, transformation, gsap

I have a simple 3d cube (BoxGeometry of 100, 100, 100) and I am trying to rotate it. If we call all 100x100x100 a tile - when I rotate it I can see it's overlapping the below tile.

(by changing color, now I totally understand the behaviour).

```
tl.to(this.cube4.rotation, 0.5, {z: -45* Math.PI/180});
```

[image]
 [[image]

What if I want to rotate it based on an anchor point of right bottom? So instead of overflowing inside the below tile, it will overflow that portion to above tile.

So it will look like the green example and not the red example:

[image] [image]

The red example here is achieved by

```
tl.to(this.cube4.rotation, 0.5, {z: -45* Math.PI/180});
tl.to(this.cube4.position, 0.5, {x: 50 }, 0.5);
```

*I am very new to three.js so if any terminology is wrong, please warn me*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the ("red") cube to a [THREE.Group](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group), in that way that the rotation axis (the edge) is in the origin of the group. This means the cube has to be shifted by the half side length.
If you rotate the group object, then the cube (which is inside the group) will rotate around the edge and not around its center.

e.g.

```js
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(cube);
cube.position.set(bbox.min.x, bbox.max.y, 0);

var pivot = new THREE.Group();
pivot.add(cube);

scene.add(pivot);
```

See also the answer to [How to center a group of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611146/how-to-center-a-group-of-objects/54611417), which uses this solution to rotate a group of objects.

---

[image]

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var camera, scene, renderer, orbitControls, pivot;
  var rot = 0.02;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(4, 1, 2);
    //camera.lookAt( -1, 0, 0 );

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    
    window.onresize = function() {
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.set(1,2,-1.5);
    scene.add( directionalLight );
    
    addGridHelper();
    createModel();

  }

  function createModel() {

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#80f080'});
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    
    var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube1.position.set(0,-0.5,-0.5);

    var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube2.position.set(0,0.5,-0.5);

    var cube3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube3.position.set(0,-0.5,0.5);

    var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#f08080'});
    var cube4 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);
    
    var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(cube4);
    cube4.position.set(bbox.min.x, bbox.max.y, 0);

    pivot = new THREE.Group();
    pivot.add(cube4);
    pivot.position.set(-bbox.min.x, 0.5-bbox.max.y, 0.5);

    scene.add(cube1);
    scene.add(cube2);
    scene.add(cube3);
    scene.add(pivot);
  }

  function addGridHelper() {
    
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100);
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orbitControls.update();
    pivot.rotation.z += rot;
    if (pivot.rotation.z > 0.0 || pivot.rotation.z < -Math.PI/2) rot *= -1;
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<!--script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></!--script-->
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r124/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r124/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: If the Group is same size with the box, wouldn't the Group's origin be center again? So  even if I rotate the group, wouldn't it be the exact same effect?

Comment: @senty Yes, the group rotates around its center. But the cube in the box is translated in relation to the center of the group.

Comment: So does the group need to be bigger than the box? I don't quite understand why it would behave differently. (sorry if it's a stupid question, i'm new to three.js)

Comment: @senty No the origin of the cube is the center of the cube. The origin of the group is the center of the group. But if you put the cube in the group whith a trnaslation, then the origin of the cube is not the origin of the group.

Comment: Now it's more clear with your snippet. Only one question, where does the cubeMatrix come from? Is it the geometry I used while creating the Box ie `var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );`?

Comment: @senty Sorry. Copy/past issue. I copied the snippet from the answer, which I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the bounds of the rotated object like this:

```
bounds = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( theRedObject )
```

Then reposition the object.y based on its bounds.min.y

```js
let scene, camera, controls, ambient, point, loader, renderer, container, stats;

const targetRotation = 0;
const targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;
const mouseX = 0;
const mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;
const windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
const windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


init();
animate();
var box, b1, b2, b3;

function init() {
  // Create a scene which will hold all our meshes to be rendered
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // Create and position a camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
     60, // Field of view
     window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, // Aspect ratio
    /*window.innerWidth / -8,
    window.innerWidth / 8,
    window.innerHeight / 8,
    window.innerHeight / -8,
    */
    0.1, // Near clipping pane
    1000 // Far clipping pane
  );
scene.add(camera)
  // Reposition the camera
  camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
  // Point the camera at a given coordinate
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  // Add orbit control
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.target.set(0, -0.5, 0);
  controls.update();

  // Add an ambient lights
  ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2);
  scene.add(ambient);

  // Add a point light that will cast shadows
  point = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
  point.position.set(25, 50, 25);
  point.castShadow = true;
  point.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
  point.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
  scene.add(point);

  group = new THREE.Group();
  group.position.y = 0;
  scene.add(group);
  rotationAnchor = new THREE.Object3D()
  group.add(rotationAnchor);

  box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(), new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 'grey'
  }))
  b1 = box.clone();
  b2 = box.clone();
  b3 = box.clone();
  b3.material = b3.material.clone()
  b3.material.color.set('red')
  group.add(box);
  group.add(b1);
  b1.position.y += 1
  group.add(b2);
  b2.position.z += 1
  rotationAnchor.add(b3);
  rotationAnchor.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 1.5)
  b3.position.set(-.5, -.5, -.5)
  // Create a renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  // Set size
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Set color
  renderer.setClearColor(0xf8a5c2);
  renderer.gammaOutput = true;
  // Enable shadow mapping
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

  // Append to the document
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  // Add resize listener
  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);

  // Enable FPS stats
  stats = new Stats();
  container.appendChild(stats.dom);

  var gui = new dat.GUI({
    height: 5 * 32 - 1
  });
  let params = {
    'test': 4,
    'bevelThickness': 1,
    'bevelSize': 1.5,
    'bevelSegments': 3
  }
  gui.add(params, 'test', 0, 10).onChange(val => {
    test = val
  })
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  rotationAnchor.rotation.z = (Math.cos(performance.now() * 0.001) * Math.PI * 0.25) + (Math.PI * 1.25)
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // Re-render scene
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  // Update stats
  stats.update();
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.2/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do I use `bounds` to rotate though? (sorry for the silly question, i'm really new to 3js)

Comment: Oh I misunderstood.. I thought you just wanted to separate the objects so they don't interpenetrate.

To rotate an object around a different point... you can make an empty THREE.Object3D(). at that point, then add your red box that object... then rotate the empty object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate that approach. Also that'd be really helpful if you can add a pseudo code in your answer

Comment: It would be really helpful if you copied that snippet for the next time you have a question, you can include the example setup. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the first image, it appears that the pivot of your red tile is at its center.

For the rotation you want, you would ideally change the pivot to the lower right of the cube. This is impossible without modifying the geometry of the cube.

BUT a simple trick is to create an empty node at that pivot point, parent your cube to that empty, and apply your rotation to the empty. (Don't forget to remove your translation, you don't need it anymore)

Here is some pseudo code, assuming your red  box is centered at (0,0,0) and has a width and height of 100:

```
// create an empty node at desired rotation pivot
var empty = new Object3D or group
empty.position = (50, -50, 0)

// parent your cube to the empty
var cube = your box
empty.add(cube)

// you may need to change the local position of your cube to bring it back to its global position of (0,0,0)
cube.position = (-50, 50, 0)

rotate empty by 45°
```

Comment: Can you please expand the simple trick part or add some pseudo code chunk to explain it?